# Basis of eigenfunctions in Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, banach-spaces, eigenfunctions

I have a question about proving the existence of a basis of eigenfunctions.

Assume we have a compact operator $L:\mathcal{B}\rightarrow\mathcal{B}$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is a Banach space of analytic even maps defined in a neighborhood of $[-1,1]$.

Since the operator is compact, I know that the spectrum is discrete. But what do I need to do in order to show that there exists a basis of eigenfunctions, i.e. $\exists f_{j}(x)\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $Lf_{j}(x)=\lambda_{j}f_{j}(x)$ and $\lbrace f_{j}(x)\rbrace$ span the whole space?

Any help will be appreciated! (this is not homework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compact operators on Banach spaces can in general be upper-triangularized---generalizing the Jordan canonical form. This means that the space is Schauder-spanned by the generalized eigenvectors. So what you would need to show is that, given any non-zero $\lambda \in \sigma(L)$, the finite dimensional subspace $\mbox{ker}(L - \lambda)$ is spanned by eigenvectors, rather than generalized eigenvectors.

Comment: More has to be said because $L=0$ is a compact operator that satisfies your criteria, but this will not give rise to a Schauder basis for any Banach space without one.

Comment: @T.A.E. do you mean I need to show other properties of $L$ before I could look for the basis of eigenfunctions? which ones?

Comment: @GregVoit : First, you need to make sure that the Banach space allows a Schauder basis. If the space is not separable, then of course it does not. Even if it is it may not admit a Schauder basis--in that case a compact operator is not necessarily approximated by finite rank operators (the converse is true, though: if it is the uniform limit of finite rank operators, then it is compact.) More about Schauder Bases: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis#Basis_problem

Answer (score 2):

See if you can extend your operator to some $L^2$ space containing your functions. Maybe your operator is even self adjoint and still compact. Use the result for compact self adjoint operators on Hilbert spaces to find a basis of eigenvectors in that $L^2$ space. Show that in fact your eigenfunctions are already in your original space. Show that any functions can be uniformly approximated by a combination of your functions.

Obs: This approach is used in one of the proofs of the theorem of Peter and Weyl.

Comment: It is interesting that $\{ e^{inx} \}_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}$ is not a Schauder basis of $L^{1}[-\pi,\pi]$, even though it is a basis of $L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]$, and these are eigenfunctions of a compact selfadjoint operator on $L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]$. There's a current question posted to that effect: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934786/exercise-31-from-chapter-4-hilbert-spaces-an-introduction-of-stein-shakar . I wonder if the integral operator is compact in $L^{1}$? Maybe a variant of it would be.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are thinking about it backwards. Every Banach space is a vector space. Every vector space has a basis.

If your eigenfunctions are:
(1) linearly independent under the inner product
(2) have the same dimension as the space.

They must be an equivalent basis.

However, neither (1) nor (2) are necessary conditions of eigenfunctions as far as I know. Its perfectly possible to have eigen functions which are not linearly independent. Its also possible to have an operator with linearly independent functions but not have enough levels in your spectrum to span the whole space. In this case, you have a set which is equivalent to some subset.

Establishing (1) and (2) is usually not difficult for physical systems.

My background is physics, so excuse the lack of formalism.

Comment: That is total nonsense, on multiple levels.