# How to solve the complex ODE $\mu f'(x) = if(x)$ in the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

My problem consists of two parts:

1. Find all the pairs $(f, \mu)$, where $f : [-\pi, \pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is differentiable satisfying $f(-\pi) = f(\pi)$ and $\mu \in \mathbb{C}$, such that for all $x \in [-\pi, \pi]$:
   $$
   \mu f'(x) = if(x)\hspace{2cm}(*)
   $$
2. How, if at all, does the answer to 1 change, if we leave out the requirement that $f(-\pi) = f(\pi)$?

---

***My attempt at a solution***

I have only been able to address question 1, and even this only partially. Here's what I've been able to accomplish.

Firstly, set $I := [-\pi, \pi]$.

For every $\mu \in \mathbb{C}$, the pair $(f := 0\mathbb{1}_I, \mu)$ satisfies $(*)$.

Now Suppose the pair $(f, \mu)$ satisfies $(*)$, but $f$ is not identically $0$. Let $x \in I$ be such that $f(x) \neq 0$.

Define $\theta_x$ to be the unique angle $\in [-\pi, \pi)$, such that $-f(x) = |f(x)|e^{i\theta_x}$ and let $\delta_x \in (0,\infty)$ be such that for all $y \in I \cap (-\delta_x, \delta_x)$,
$$
f(y) \in B_{f(x)}(|f(x)|) := \{y \in \mathbb{C}\mid: |y - f(x)| < |f(x)|\}
$$

Then for every $y \in I \cap (-\delta_x, \delta_x)$, $f(y)$ is contained inside the domain of the logarithm branch $\log_{\theta_x}$. We therefore have, for all $y \in I \cap (-\delta_x, \delta_x)$,
$$
i \mu^{-1} = \frac{f'(y)}{f(y)} = \log_{\theta_x}'(f(y))
$$
Therefore, for all $y \in I \cap (-\delta_x, \delta_x)$ we have
$$
\log_{\theta_x}(f(y)) = i\mu^{-1}y + C
$$
for some $C \in \mathbb{C}$, and hence
$$
f(y) = e^Ce^{i\mu^{-1}y}
$$
i.e.,
$$
f(y) = C'e^{i\mu^{-1}y}
$$
for some $C' \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

To summarize the results of our investigation so far: we have found out that if $(f,\mu)$ is a pair that satisfies $(*)$ and if $x \in I$ is such that $f(x) \neq 0$, then there is a neighborhood of $x$ in $I$, where
$$
f(y) = C_xe^{i\mu^{-1}y}
$$
for some $C_x \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. (Clearly, $C_x$ is uniquely determined in said neighborhood, hence $C_x$ is defined unambiguously for all $x \in I$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$.) It can be readily seen that if $\emptyset \neq J \subseteq [-\pi, \pi]$ is any open interval where $f$ does not assume the value $0$, we have
$$
C_x = C_y,\ \forall x, y \in J
$$
and we may therefore define unambiguously $C_J$ to be the unique complex number, such that
$$
f(y) = C_Je^{i\mu^{-1}y}
$$
for all $y \in J$.

Now define $Z := \{y \in I \mid: f(y) = 0\}$, $N := I\setminus Z$ and define $\mathcal{J}$ to be the set of all maximal open intervals $\subseteq I$ such that
$$
N = \bigcup_{J \in \mathcal{J}} J
$$
(we allow two of the intervals in $\mathcal{J}$ to contain $-\pi$ and/or $\pi$ if $f(-\pi) \neq 0$ or $f(\pi) \neq 0$.)

Then for every $J \in \mathcal{J}$ we have:
$$
f(y) = C_Je^{i\mu^{-1}y},\hspace{1cm} y \in J
$$

***Here's where I'm stuck:***

Is it possible to determine that there is some unique $C \in \mathbb{C}$, such that if $(*)$ holds for all $x \in I$, we must have $f(x) = Ce^{-i\mu^{-1}x}$ for all $x \in I$?

An answer to this question hinges on the following two questions: Is the set $Z$ empty? If not, and if $J, K \in \mathcal{J}$ are distinct, do we necessarily have $C_J = C_K$?

Comment: It seems that you did not impose the condition $f(−π)=f(π)$ in part 1. This gives a restriction on the values that $μ$ can have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow... You might want to replace everything in your solution by the observation that, when $\mu\ne0$, $(\ast)$ is *equivalent* to $$\mathrm e^{-ix/\mu}f'(x)-(i/\mu)\mathrm e^{-ix/\mu}f(x)=0,$$ which is *equivalent* to the fact that $$\mathrm e^{-ix/\mu}f(x)$$ does not depend on $x$. (And the case $\mu=0$ is even simpler.)

Motto: In the complex plane, exponentials are good but logarithms are... well, perhaps not *bad* but *complicated*...

Answer (score 0):

An answer was given by [T.A.E.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/112478/t-a-e) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/935108/37058) (look for the bold-type "Added"). From that answer it turns out that it is indeed possible to determine that there is some unique $C \in \mathbb{C}$, such that if $(*)$ holds for all $x \in I$, we must have $f(x) = Ce^{-i\mu^{-1}x}$ for all $x \in I$, and therefore, unless $f \equiv 0$, the set $Z$ empty.